# When upgrading from Django 1.7 - 1.8, I get ImportError: Could not import 'serve'. The path must be fully qualified

Tags: django, url, upgrade, importerror

I'm upgrading my project from 1.7 to 1.8, and I'm coming up with this problem about the inability to import "serve".  This is happening on all of my pages, including the admin page (minus the template url tag being shown).  I can't find anyone else having this error or any notes about "serve" in the release notes.

Any clue what the issue is?

```
Internal Server Error: /feed/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 164, in get_response
response = response.render()
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 158, in render
self.content = self.rendered_content
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 135, in rendered_content
content = template.render(context, self._request)
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 74, in render
return self.template.render(context)
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 209, in render
return self._render(context)
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 201, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render
bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py", line 79, in render_node
return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 135, in render
return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 201, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render
bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py", line 79, in render_node
return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 135, in render
return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 201, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render
bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py", line 79, in render_node
return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 329, in render
return nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render
bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py", line 79, in render_node
return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 493, in render
url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 579, in reverse
return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 433, in _reverse_with_prefix
self._populate()
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 326, in _populate
lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern, pattern.default_args))
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 247, in callback
self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\utils\lru_cache.py", line 101, in wrapper
result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
File "C:\Users\JBLT\Envs\django18\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 103, in get_callable
lookup_view)
ImportError: Could not import 'serve'. The path must be fully qualified.
```

feed/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from feed.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/hide/$', login_required(FeedPostHideView.as_view()), name='feed_post_hide'),
    #url(r'^$', login_required(PostHideView.as_view()), name='feed_post_hide'),
    url(r'^$', login_required(FeedPostListView.as_view(template_name='feed/feedpost_list.html')), name='feed_post_list'),
]
```

src/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic import *
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from profile.models import Profile
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView, RedirectView
from datetime import datetime
from django.conf.urls import url, include

urlpatterns = [
               url(r'^images/defaultavatar/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/images/profiles/default_avatar.png'), name='default_avatar'),
                        url(r'^static/images/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve',
                            {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/images/'}, name='images'),
                        url(r'^static/stylesheets/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve',
                            {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/stylesheets/'}, name='stylesheets'),
                        url(r'^static/javascript/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve',
                            {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/javascript/'}, name='javascript'),
                        url(r'^static/files/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve',
                            {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/files/'}, name='files'),
                        url(r'^static/ads/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/ads/'},
                            name='ads'),
                        url(r'^static/photos/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve',
                            {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/photos/'}, name='photos'),
                        url(r'^static/icons/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve',
                            {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/icons/'}, name='icons'),

                        # media for srd documents
                        url(r'^media/documents/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve',
                            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/documents/'}, name='documents'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),          
    url(r'^feed/', include('feed.urls')),
]
```

Line giving error:

```
{% url 'feed_post_list' %}
```

Currently, I have my project laid out like this:

```
PROJECT NAME
 PROJECT NAME
  TEMPLATES
   APP
    feedpost_flist.html
  urls.py
 APP
  urls.py
```

Could it be an issue with the feed.urls not able to find the template files?

Comment: Is that really your full `src/urls.py`? What does `feed/views.py` look like?

Comment: No, but it's a large file.  I've updated it with the imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.  The usse was using 'serve' in the urls.

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^static/images/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve',
]
```

changed to

```
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^static/images/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,
]
```